# Connect Python to Remote DB2 Server

Tags: python, linux, db2

Using Python's DB2 API, [ibm_db](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054368.html), I am attempting to connect to a remote DB2 server (at IP address 10.0.0.001 which I can successfully `ssh` into). Both client and server machines are Linux / Ubuntu 16.0 LTS. In all my attempts and solutions, I continually run into the regular `SQL1639N` error.

**Python 3.5** *(attempted both connection versions)*

```
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi

# DB CONNECT
#dsn = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=MYDB;HOSTNAME=10.0.0.001;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=OEM;PWD=****;"
#db = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")

db = ibm_db.connect("Server=127.0.0.1:50000;Hostname=10.0.0.001;Database=MYDB;UID=OEM;PWD=****;", "", "")
```

**Error**

> [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1639N  The database server was unable to perform
>   authentication because security-related database manager files on the
>   server do not have the required operating system permissions. 
>   SQLSTATE=08001 SQLCODE=-1639

**User**

The user listed above in connection string, OEM, is:

1. server machine's root super user
2. name of only instance of DB2 installation (not `db2inst1`)
3. name of schema database resides in

OEM maintains the DBADM privileges. Below are all grantees of MYDB database. If OEM requires the *CONNECT* attribute please let me know how to grant it as I cannot connect with *any* other user including `db2admin`.

```
GRANTEE  TYPE DBADM CREATETAB BINDADD CONNECT NOFENCE IMPLSCHEMA LOAD EXTROUTINE QUIESCECONN LIBADM SECURITYADM
-------- ---- ----- --------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---- ---------- ----------- ------ -----------
OEM      U    Y     N         N       N       N       N          N    N          N           N      Y          
PUBLIC   G    N     Y         Y       Y       N       Y          N    N          N           N      N
```

**Server**

Relatedly, on the server, I cannot connect to database with OEM and password (using server machine root's password). However, I can without any specified user.

*Fails*

```
db2 connect to MYDB user OEM
Enter current password for OEM: <entered anonymously>

SQL1639N  The database server was unable to perform authentication because 
security-related database manager files on the server do not have the required 
operating system permissions.  SQLSTATE=08001
```

*Succeeds*

```
db2 connect to MYDB

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 11.1.2.2
 SQL authorization ID   = OEM
 Local database alias   = MYDB
```

---

Below are my attempted solutions per IBM's own guidelines. And yes, I did stop and start DB2 with commands: `dbstop` and `dbstart`.

**Solution 1** [IBM link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01639n.html)

Attempting to run `./db2iupdt -k OEM` for both OEM and a non-root superuser, I received the following.

```
DBI20127E  The command failed because it is not supported or is invalid.
```

Then adding sudo comamnd, `sudo ./db2iupdt -k OEM`, I received the following:

```
DBI1152E  To run this program, you can not be root user.

Explanation: 

db2iupdt can not be run by users with root authority.

User response: 

Rerun the command as a non-root user.
```

**Solution 2** [IBM link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21987678)

Changing the ownership level to allow `set-user-id`, *s*, for these two security files, *db2chpw* and *db2ckpw*, made no difference as error persisted from Python.

Please advise on anything I need to do to diagnose and ultimately resolve the connection issue. Being new to DB2, I would also ask you to clarify items like *node* and *catalog* if part of your answer.

---

*Instance Owner* [IBM link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056169.html)

```
db2 connect to MYDB
db2 "values SYSPROC.AUTH_GET_INSTANCE_AUTHID()"

1              
----------------
OEM
```

*sqllib permission*

```
ls -l /home/oem/sqllib

drwxr-xr-x  2 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 acs
drwxr-xr-x  2 oem oem  4096 Oct 29 10:18 adm
drwxr-xr-x  2 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 adsm
drwxr-x---  2 oem oem  4096 Oct 29 10:18 backup
drwxr-xr-x  3 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 bnd
-rw-r--r--  1 oem oem     0 Oct 29 10:18 cat
drwxrwsr-t  3 oem oem  4096 Nov 14 19:47 cfg
drwxrwsr-t  2 oem oem  4096 Oct 29 10:18 cfgcache
drwxr-xr-x  4 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 conv
drwxrwsr-t  2 oem oem  4096 Nov 14 19:49 ctrl
drwxrwxr-x  3 oem oem  4096 Nov 14 19:47 ctrlha
drwxrwxr-x  2 oem oem  4096 Oct 29 10:18 ctrlhamirror
-rwxr-xr-x  1 oem oem 12891 Oct 29 10:18 db2cshrc
drwxrwsrwt  5 oem oem  4096 Nov 16 21:06 db2dump
-rwxr-xr-x  1 oem oem  9017 Oct 29 10:18 db2profile
-rw-rw-r--  1 oem oem 28672 Dec 17 13:38 db2systm
drwxr-xr-x  5 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 desktop
drwxr-xr-x  3 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 doc
drwxr-xr-x  8 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 dsdriver
drwxr-xr-x  5 oem oem  4096 Oct 29 10:18 function
-rw-r--r--  1 oem oem   277 Oct 29 10:18 global.reg
drwxr-xr-x  3 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 gskit
drwxr-xr-x  5 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 ha
drwx------  3 oem oem  4096 Oct 29 10:18 hmonCache
drwxr-xr-x  2 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 include
drwxr-xr-x  4 oem oem  4096 Jun 10  2017 infopop
drwxr-xr-x  4 oem oem  4096 Oct 29 10:25 install
drwxr-xr-x  4 oem oem  4096 Oct 29 10:18 instance
...
```

*Authentication* parameter

```
db2 get dbm cfg | grep -i auth

GSS Plugin for Local Authorization    (LOCAL_GSSPLUGIN) = 
Server Connection Authentication          (SRVCON_AUTH) = NOT_SPECIFIED
Database manager authentication        (AUTHENTICATION) = SERVER
Alternate authentication           (ALTERNATE_AUTH_ENC) = NOT_SPECIFIED
Cataloging allowed without authority   (CATALOG_NOAUTH) = NO
Trusted client authentication          (TRUST_CLNTAUTH) = CLIENT
Bypass federated authentication            (FED_NOAUTH) = NO
```

Comment: I may be stating the obvious, but `"Server=127.0.0.1:50000;` is **never** a remote machine ...

Comment: It will not work from Python until and unless it works at the command-line on the Db2 server.  Can you confirm if account OEM is the instance-owner account?    Can you confirm if the instance-owner account has 755 permissions on files and directories in ~$DB2INSTANCE/sqllib tree?  Can you also confirm the ownerships of files and directories in that tree ?   Also what is the value of the AUTHENTICATION  dbm cfg parameter on the server?

Comment: Regarding "node" and "catalog". For any Db2-client , think of a node to mean "a pointer to a Db2-instance, which can be local or remote, and that instance may be on Linux/Unix/Windows, or Z/OS (a subsystem), or OS/400.  A Db2-client can then declare that databases exist on a node. Your Db2-client can define many nodes and many-databases (pointers to databases).  The action of defining a node, or defining a database on a node  is called cataloging, so at the command line you catalog a node, and then catalog databases on nodes, and you can uncatalog them also. Like create/remove pointer.

Comment: See extended post hopefully to answer your items. OEM looks to be instance owner with needed sqllib permissions.

Comment: On the Db2-server hostname, become the instance-owner , use `db2diag -A` to archive the current diagnostics file, then use `db2 update dbm cfg using DIAGLEVEL 4 immediate` and when that completes, use `db2 connect to MYDB user OEM using password` and when it fails, please study the db2diag.log entries and post the relevant ERROR and WARNING entries. Then revert the DIAGLEVEL to 3 which is the default.   Additionally, check db2iupdt runs as the instance-owner only on the server-instance .

Comment: @mao ... Thank you for these instructions. I actually found a solution to my issue by enabling os authentication in the [db2rfe config](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0050570.html) file. I will answer later today.

Comment: OK it was not previously stated that it was a non-root install of Db2. I never recommend that feature because of the many maintenance hassles it introduces.

Comment: @mao ... I am completely new to DB2 setup. I still believe it is a root install and OEM is the instance-owner, so frankly I do not understand what the issue is especially trying IBM's own instructions. If you can explain the issue with a working solution I will happily invite you to answer below. I did not have time to run your steps. I will do so, reverting back to default `db2rfe` config.

Comment: To find the numeric uid of the account that installed Db2 on Unix, become the instance-owner (e.g su or sudo) and run at the shell the command `db2greg -dump | grep ^S` .  This will show a few lines comma separated values and the final field on each line is the UID. If the Db2 was installed as root then the value will be 0.  You can also consult the installation log file created by the Db2 installation which should show this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what the true fix was but I eventually was able to connect DB2 on server to client machine using Python with following steps.

1. Changed ownership of security files, *db2chpw* and *db2ckp*w

   ```
   chmod 4511 db2chpw

   chmod 4511 db2ckpw
   ```
2. Changed the *db2irct* config file (in ~/sqllib/instance directory) to allow the following (NO to YES):

   ```
   ENABLE_OS_AUTHENTICATION=YES

   RESERVE_REMOTE_CONNECTION=YES
   ```
3. Ran the config file

   ```
   ./db2rfe -f db2rfe.cfg
   ```

   This also started the db2 svcename, *db2c_oem*, at a different port, 48000, listed later in the config file. On a previous attempted fix, I had manually entered *db2c_inst1* svcename in dbm cfg file which I removed here. Maybe that was the real issue?

With above changes I was able to locally connect on the server machine:

```
db2 connect to MYDB 
Enter current password for OEM: <entered anonymously>

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 11.1.2.2
 SQL authorization ID   = OEM
 Local database alias   = MYDB
```

And I was able to remotely connect with client machine but adjusted the port and slightly changed second connection string using explicit *Port* argument. Both versions below correctly work:

```
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi

# DB CONNECT
#dsn = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=MYDB;HOSTNAME=10.0.0.001;PORT=48000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=OEM;PWD=****;"
#db = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")

db = ibm_db.connect("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=48000;Hostname=10.0.0.001;Database=MYDB;UID=OEM;PWD=****;", "", "")
```

Interestingly, I reverted back `ENABLE_OS_AUTHENTICATION` and `RESERVE_REMOTE_CONNECTION` to NO and then re-ran the config file and I was still able to successfully connect!